# tickmarkPlacement 'between' doesn't work

Tags: highcharts

I want to use tickmarkplacement 'between' as given [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement) in my Highchart plot. but I figure out that it works only if 'categories' is given. 
How to use it without setting categories ?
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AeV7h/12/) is an example plot where I want to use property 'tickmarkplacement:between'.

```
   $(function () {


var data=[[16,10],[24,3],[30,7],[48,8]];
var param= {
            Name: "Current speed",
            Color: "#C6C6C6 ",
            LineStyle: "Solid",
            SeriesType: "line",
            LineWidth: 2,
            TickInterval: null,
            MinValue: null,
            MaxValue: null,
            Decimals: 2
            };

$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            plotBorderColor: '#E4E4E4',
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                useHTML: true,
                text: param.Name + "( m/s  )",
            },
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            min: param.MinValue,
            max: param.MaxValue,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
            tickInterval: param.TickInterval,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'between'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Depth(m)',
            },
            reversed: true,
            tickLength: 50,
            gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot'
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: param.Name,
            data: data,
            color: param.Color,
            dashStyle: param.LineStyle,
            lineWidth: param.LineWidth,
            type: "line"
        }]
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement) it works only with the categories on the xAxis.